# Computed not running when updated from emitted event vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm kinda a noob at vue js, however I can't seem to understand why the allValid event isn't being emitted from the following code: (snippet here, full code in the js fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/sTX7y/674/

```
Vue.component('password-validator', {
    template: `
<ul>
    <regex-validation regex='.{6,}' v-on:valid='v => { isLongEnough = v }' :input='input'> 
    Is Long Enough
    </regex-validation>
    <regex-validation regex='[A-Z]' v-on:valid='v => { hasUppercase = v }' :input='input'>
    Has Upper
    </regex-validation>
</ul>
    `,
    props: [ 'input' ],
    data: function(){
        return {
            isLongEnough: false,
            hasUppercase: false,
        }
    },
    computed:{
        isValid: function(){
            var valid = this.isLongEnough && this.hasUppercase;
            this.$emit('allValid', valid);
            return valid;
        }
    }
});
```

When viewing this using the vue chrome extension I can clearly see that isLongEnough and hasUppercase both flip from true to false, (and the validation is reflected on the output).  It's just that the last isValid computed function just never seems to run...

Thanks for the help and if you see any other noob mistakes feel free to chime in on how I could do this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed function is defined correctly in the `password-validator` component.  The only problem is you have referenced it ouside of the component scope.  i.e. `{{ isValid }}` is in the html outside of the template.  To correct this you can change the `password-validator` template thus:

```
template: `
<ul>
    <regex-validation regex='.{6,}' v-on:valid='v => { isLongEnough = v }' :input='input'> 
    Is Long Enough
    </regex-validation>
    <regex-validation regex='[A-Z]' v-on:valid='v => { hasUppercase = v }' :input='input'>
    Has Upper
    </regex-validation>
    Is Valid: {{ isValid }}
</ul>
```

now that the reference to the computed property `isValid` is inside the template, it should update accordingly.

Updated the fiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTX7y/676/)